# Add rho as icon in valueBox

Tags: r, shiny, icons, shinydashboard, flexdashboard

Can I add a **rho** (Greek letter small) as an icon to a value box in RShiny?
For example, with the following code snippet, I have created a value box that has the € symbol as an icon:

```
valueBox(winterMean, subtitle = "Mean Winter", color = "black", icon = icon("euro-sign"))
```

This gives the following value box:

[image]

How can I replace the € symbol by a small rho?

Comment: I think it uses fontawesome to get icons, not sure if Rho is implemented, there is an open issue on GitHub: https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/5842

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can add custom Greek letters using [Unicode Character "ρ" (U+03C1)](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+03C1) through custom *css*, see example:

### Using flexdashboard:

Our example *rmd* file:

````
---
title: "My Rho"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    css: styles.css
---

```{r}
library(flexdashboard)

valueBox(42, caption = "My Rho", icon = "fa-rho")
```
````

And additional *styles.css* file:

```
.fa-rho:before {
    font-weight: 700;
    content: '\03c1';
}
```

Output:

[image]

**Note:** For my test I kept *css* file in the same folder as *rmd* file, but it could be in any subfolder, then we need to define the full path in *rmd*, e.g.: `resources/css/styles.css`.

---

### Using shinydashboard

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    includeCSS("styles.css"),
    valueBox(42, "My Rho", icon = icon("rho")),
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this information. Where do I add the styles.css file? I'm new to Rshiny

Comment: ---
title: "My Rho"
author: "MK"
date: "28 9 2020"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    css: styles.css
---


.fa-rho:before {
    font-weight: 700;
    content: '\03c1';
}

Like this?

Comment: @Michi No styles.css is a separate file from your rmd file.

Comment: So in the css.file there are only your 4 lines from above?

Comment: @Michi yes, exactly.

Comment: When using this now here in the server: ```valueBox(corrCoefficient, subtitle = "Correlation Coefficient", color = "black", icon = icon(fa-rho))``` this doesn't gives the expected rho in the value box. It gives an error message: The following error happened while creating the value box for the correlation coefficient: Error in valueBox(corrCoefficient, subtitle = "Correlation Coefficient", : unused argument (subtitle = "Correlation Coefficient")

Comment: @Michi I am using flexdashboard, your valueBox looks like is coming from shinydashboard package.

Comment: Alright, is this possible with shinydashboard package? Because I have already done many customized tags/style... if I use now the flexdashboard this will remove all pre defined styles.

Comment: [Here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html) is a tutorial how to include css into shiny

Comment: @zx8754 thank you! But how looks then the RMD file?

Comment: @MichiThere is no rmd file, this is shiydashboard.

Comment: @zx8754 oh ok, and the styles.css there must be ```.rho:before{}``` instead of ```.fa-rho:before{}```??

Comment: @Michi No styles.css is the same file for both shinydashboard and flexdashboard.

Comment: @zx8754 Thank you for your help! It doesn't work for me at the moment, and I hope I can still find the bug. Thank you!

Comment: @Michi In shiny it might matter where the css file is, maybe try to keep it in www folder: `www/styles.css`